# import musicplayer, sys, os, fnmatch, random, pprint, Tkinter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'musicplayer'

Tags: python

```
  File "C:/Users/pc/projecys/testmuysic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import musicplayer, sys, os, fnmatch, random, pprint, Tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'musicplayer'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The policy of this site is to show your effort to solve the problem. That means you would have to provide your code to better help and to see what exactly you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to install it 
python pip install musicplayer